# How to add a git repository to Ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, git, ubuntu

I have a node.js project local in my computer, right now, I want to push this project to remote Ubuntu server. I have create a project.git on Ubuntu server, and pushed to it. Right now, I want to run this project on the server, but how do I access this folder, it's just a git directory. The process I am following is like below:

Ubuntu server:

```
mkdir /home/git/project
cd /home/git/project
git init
```

Local computer:

```
git remote add origin root@someserver.com:/home/git/project
git add .
git commit -am "Initial Commit"
git push origin master
```

It push succeed. Right now, I want to execute this node.js project and run it on the server, but how to turn this git repository to a folder, so I can cd into it and then node app.js after?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the code on the server side, you should init the repository without `--bare` option or clone it somewhere else on the server.

Bare repositories store only git specific files.

**UPDATE:**
If you create a repository without `--bare` option, you can't push anything to that branch where your server is staying. Better solution is if you create a bare repository and clone it somewhere else on the server. Notice that, you should use there `git pull` command if you want to see your fresh code.

Comment: Just git init on the server side?

Comment: Yes, just a simple init without `--bare` option and the repository will contain your committed files.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But after I push some file to the master. I can't see the files on the server. But the push are success.

Comment: You should use `git pull`, but I've just rembered that you can't push anything to that branch, where you stay on a non-bare remote. So I've updated my answer with more explanation and a better soultion.